# Pystan Posterior Uncertainty Intervals

Tags: python, optimization, confidence-interval, uncertainty, pystan

I saw [on another forum](https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/397) that PyStan doesn’t have the same function as RStan where they use `posterior_interval()`, but we can use `numpy.percentile()` instead. I’m currently using the [`pystan.StanModel.optimizing()`](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pystan.StanModel.optimizing) function in PyStan to get the set of parameters that maximize the posterior likelihood. I now would also like to obtain an outer 95% confidence interval for the posterior result, so I am wondering whether the `numpy.percentile()` function would be used with the `optimizing` function?

I tried finding the 95% interval of the parameter distribution, but that did not give a good confidence interval around the result.  In particular, I don't consider it good since when I expect the posterior to present a multimodal distribution, the confidence interval I conduct using `numpy.percentile()` is inside the posterior 2-D gaussian patch.

I think the 95% interval would have to be taken from the posterior. **Would I use the percentile function with the optimizing function to obtain a 95% confident posterior result?**

Comment: @merv here is the link: https://github.com/stan-dev/pystan/issues/397. I wouldn't consider the confidence "good" since when I expect the posterior to present a multimodal distribution, the confidence interval I conduct using np.percentile() is inside the posterior 2-D gaussian patch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain bounds on posterior estimates requires sampling the posterior, which `pystan.StanModel.optimizing` does not do.  Instead, use the [`pystan.StanModel.sampling`](https://pystan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pystan.StanModel.sampling) method to generate MCMC draws from the posterior.

If you just need readouts of standard confidence bounds, then the `pystan.StanFit.stansummary()` method might be sufficient, as this will print the 2.5%, 25%, 50%, 75%, and 97.5% quantiles for each parameter.  For example,

```
fit = sm.sampling(...) # eight schools model
print(fit.stansummary())
```

> ```
> Inference for Stan model: anon_model_19a09b474d1901f191444eaf8a6b8ce2.
> 4 chains, each with iter=10000; warmup=5000; thin=1;  post-warmup
> draws per chain=5000, total post-warmup draws=20000.
>
>            mean se_mean     sd   2.5%    25%    50%   75%  97.5%   n_eff   Rhat 
> mu         7.98    0.05   5.04   -2.0   4.76   7.91  11.2   18.2   10614    1.0 
> tau        6.54    0.08   5.65   0.24   2.49   5.25   8.98  20.65   4552    1.0 
> eta[0]     0.39  6.7e-3   0.94  -1.53  -0.23   0.42   1.02   2.18  20000    1.0 
> eta[1]   3.3e-4  6.2e-3   0.88  -1.74  -0.58-2.5e-3   0.57   1.75  20000    1.0 
> eta[2]     -0.2  6.6e-3   0.93  -2.01  -0.84  -0.22   0.41   1.68  20000    1.0 
> eta[3]    -0.03  6.3e-3   0.89   -1.8  -0.61  -0.03   0.56   1.75  20000    1.0 
> eta[4]    -0.35  6.7e-3   0.88  -2.04  -0.94  -0.36   0.22   1.44  17344    1.0 
> eta[5]    -0.22  6.6e-3    0.9  -1.96  -0.81  -0.24   0.35   1.59  18298    1.0 
> eta[6]     0.34  6.8e-3   0.88  -1.43  -0.23   0.36   0.93   2.04  16644    1.0 
> eta[7]     0.05  6.6e-3   0.93  -1.77  -0.58   0.04   0.66   1.88  20000    1.0 
> theta[0]   11.4    0.07   8.23  -1.83   6.04  10.22  15.42  31.52  13699    1.0 
> theta[1]   7.93    0.04   6.21  -4.58   4.09   7.89  11.79  20.48  20000    1.0 
> theta[2]   6.17    0.06   7.72 -11.43   2.06   6.65  10.85  20.53  16367    1.0 
> theta[3]   7.72    0.05   6.53  -5.29   3.68    7.7  11.75  21.04  20000    1.0 
> theta[4]   5.14    0.04   6.35  -9.35   1.44   5.64   9.38  16.49  20000    1.0 
> theta[5]   6.11    0.05   6.66  -8.44   2.22   6.44  10.41  18.52  20000    1.0 
> theta[6]  10.63    0.05   6.76  -1.25   6.04  10.08  14.51  25.66  20000    1.0 
> theta[7]    8.4    0.06   7.85  -7.56   3.89   8.17  12.76   25.3  16584    1.0 
> lp__      -4.89    0.04   2.63 -10.79  -6.47  -4.66  -3.01  -0.43   5355    1.0
> ```

Or if you need specific quantiles, you would use `numpy.percentile` as you mentioned.

However, as you correctly observe, this is inappropriate for multimodal distributions. This case is addressed in [a different answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53671925/570918), but note that if one expects multiple modes *a priori*, a mixture model is typically used to separate the modes out into distinct unimodal random variables.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve the percentiles you wish straight from `pystan.stansummary`:

```
percentiles = (0.025, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.975)              # edit these at will
pystan.stansummary(fit=your_fit, probs=percentiles, digits_summary=2)
```

This should work fine.